# ibeacon send remote data / two way communication

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, iot

Is it possible for an iOS/Android app to transmit data to a remote server when it picks up an iBeacon signal. The app will run in the background.

Lets assume the iBeacon is equipped with an internet connection as well. Will the beacon be able to pick up the data transmitted from the smartphone app?

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. An IoT device works as an iBeacon (and motion sensor)
2. The IoT device picks up motion via the sensor
3. The IoT contacts a remote server to find out if a given smartphone is within close range of it.
4. The IoT performs some sort of operation based upon if the smartphone is close or not.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and No.**

Yes, an iOS/Android app in the background can transmit data to a remote server when it detects an iBeacon signal.  This is a very common use case, and I have built several apps that do this.

No, an iBeacon cannot send data to a server for two reasons:

1. An iBeacon is a transmit only device.  It does nothing more than regularly send out an advertisement packet with a unique identifier.  By design, it does not listen or receive. While you could certainly build some other custom Bluetooth LE device that does this, it would not be a standard iBeacon.
2. Typically iBeacon devices do not have internet connections.

What you describe is certainly possible if you build a general purpose computer with an internet connection that also sends out an iBeacon transmission as a small part of what it does.  I have built such systems out of Raspberry Pi computers, and stationary Android/iOS devices.  But you could also do this with a laptop, desktop, or smaller embedded device.

The key distinction in being able to do this is recognizing that you can't just buy an off-the-shelf iBeacon and make this work.  You have to build your own IoT device based on a small computer with an internet connection that is augmented to transmit an iBeacon advertisement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer david. Much appreciated :)